# python output data type confusion

Tags: python, sorting, buffer

Hi all this is the code I am trying to run. I am not a computer scientist and I know this is an easy answer I just do not have the tools to answer it. I am trying to get this list printed to a text file. It works if I print to screen. The error I get is this: "TypeError: expected a character buffer object"

here is the code

```
input = open('Tyger.txt', 'r')
text = input.read()
wordlist = text.split()

output_file = open ('FrequencyList.txt','w')
wordfreq = [wordlist.count(p) for p in wordlist]

#Pair words with corresponding frequency

dictionary = dict(zip(wordlist,wordfreq))

#Sort by inverse Frequency and print

aux = [(dictionary[key], key) for key in dictionary]
aux.sort()
aux.reverse()

for a in aux: output_file.write(a)
```

Thanks!

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but you should consider using [the `with` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) for opening files. You might also want to look into [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) where counting things, and in your list comprehension of dictionary items, `[(value, key) for key, value in dictionary.items()]` - using [`dict.items()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) means you don't have to keep calling dictionary lookups, which is nicer to read.

Comment: I'd start by changing `output_file.write(a)` to `output_file.write(str(a))`.  When you print it to the screen, it does an implicit string conversion before printing.  Writing to a file does no such thing.

Comment: what is `type(a)` it should be a string.  You can cast it to a string using `str(a)`

Comment: Thank-you, both your comments are very helpful. I do not know much about programming and I was trying output_file.write str(a)

Comment: Oh, and further to my earlier comment, if you are using Python 2.x, you will want `iteritems()` or `viewitems()` over just `items()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in the comments above, change `output_file.write(a)` to `output_file.write(str(a))`.  When you `print` something, Python attempts to do an implicit string conversion of whatever you are printing.  That is why `print`ing a tuple (as you are doing here) works.  `file.write()` does no implicit conversion, so you have to covert it yourself with `str()`.

As noted in the comments to this answer, you probably need to call `.close()` on the file.

Comment: sr2222 this has corrected the error and the program runs through but it does not print anything in the output file. Am I doing something else wrong

Comment: Maybe you should 
    close() 
the file? Like... 
    output_file.close()

Comment: Could also just set `sys.stdout = open ('FrequencyList.txt','wt')` and use `print` statements. If you do this you'll also need to save and restore the original value of `sys.stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

you can write your code like:

```
input = open('tyger.txt','r').read().split()
......
.........
............
for a in aux:
    output_file.write(str(a))
    output_file.close()
```

you must `close()` a file what you have opened to write,otherwise you won't be able to use the file.